# PIL ImageChop giving wrong results:

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

```
img1_path = r'/Users/siddharth/image1.png'
img2_path = r'/Users/siddharth/image2.png'

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageChops

im1 = Image.open(img1_path) # original
im2 = Image.open(img2_path) # scapred

height,width = im1.size


for h in range(0,height,height/25):
    for w in range(0,width,width/20):
        c_img1 = im1.crop((h,w,height/25,height/25))
        c_img2 = im2.crop((h,w,height/25,height/25))

        if ImageChops.difference(c_img1, c_img2).getbbox() is None:
            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
            draw.rectangle((h,w,height/25,height/25),outline='red')

im2.save('Diff.png')
print 'Done'
```

The idea here is two compare two images and mark rectangles in areas where they differ.
The problem is despite multiple attempts my results (Diff.img) has rectangles all over as opposed to having just around differences?

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Change the `is None` to `is not None`?

Comment: yes Sir its not None,nevertheless it should then mark similarities,it doesnt do that

Comment: Wait, since when is it supposed to mark similarities? Nothing like that was mentioned in the question. (And there also isn't any code that would do that, so it's no surprise that it's not happening.)

Comment: @Aran-Fey. Checking if the bounding box of the non-zero portion is None is consistent with checking for similarities. It appears that the code and the prose don't match?